# Can we send a HTTP request from a stored procedure in any database?

Tags: database, httpwebrequest

I tried googling but couldn't find any relevant article. I am not sure if its possible or not.

Could you please share any thing relevant about this title? It could be either a get or post http request.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has [UTL_HTTP](http://psoug.org/reference/utl_http.html)

In SQL Server, you would probably [use the CLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094.aspx), which gives you .NET framework access

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I can think of is *Native XML Web Services* in SQL Server.  But that functionality was deprecated in SQL Server 2008.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280436.aspx